# How do I NOT display input text in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason this is making me nuts.  I have a web page with a login using two input fields at [ http://pubsgrants.com/app/login.html ]

```
<input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" >

<input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" >

<button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" onclick="doSignin();" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
```

I have a simple function that checks the textinput and if it is not a certain value it says on the page. If it is correct it goes to the application.  My problem is if the login is is incorrect it puts everything in the address bar, such as:

> http://pubsgrants.com/app/login.html?textinput=stuff&passwordinput=pass&singlebutton=#

How do I stop this?  Is this the normal behavior?

Comment: what does `doSignin` look like?

Comment: Please include the script you are referring to into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For immediate fix you can move button outside the form block;

```
<form>
   <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" >
  <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" >
</form>

<button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" onclick="doSignin();" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From

```
<form action="" method="GET">
```

To

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

This will hide whatever values you are sending within you form.

Normally, POST are used when sensitive data is sent. In your case you used GET. Using GET method for logins is not a norm.

Comment: He doesn't even have the `method` attribute in his code... You can post comments. Why not do so?